# Binding dynamic list to comboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this following issue with wpf.
I have a class `Row` which has multiple attributes which are from two types of classes `DataEntry` and `ADEntry`.
the user can mape between `DataEntry` and `ADEntry` items, which means creating a row or more, and save his configuration or load it then too. 
the data should come from a database.

I have created a `Grid` like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="fieldGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

in the `Grid` there is `DataTemplate`, in it is my `combobox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ADAttributes}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Entry.ADEntryName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

the list `ADAttributes` is generated in the ViewModel once the user enters the connection string, so it is at runtime generated.

ViewModel:

```
 public class MainWindowVM : _NotifyPropertyChanged
{

  private ObservableCollection<ADEntry> aDAttributes;
    public ObservableCollection<ADEntry> ADAttributes
    {
        get
        {

            return this.aDAttributes;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.aDAttributes)
            {
                this.aDAttributes = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MainWindowVM.ADAttributes));
            }
        }
    }

 MainWindowVM()
 {
     ADAttributes = new ObservableCollection<ADEntry>();
 }
```

Now the methode which updates the `ObservableCollection` when the user has given SQL-Server login data:

```
 public void IsConnected(object value)
    {
       this.ADAttributes = GetADEntryFromDB(dbName);  
    }
```

When the list was static and as static resource defined worked everything fine.

complete code is this:

Code behinde for the static case which worked fine:

```
this.vm = new MainWindowVM();
this.DataContext = this.vm;
this.Resources.Add("ADAttributes", this.vm.ADAttributes)
this.Resources.Add("DataAttributes", this.vm.DataAttributes)
```

I can not modify the static resources at run time and the lists are unavailable in the `ComboBox` Tag, but they are outside the `Grid` available.
I mean when I copy the same `ComboBox` outside the Grid, Iget the data, like this:

```
     <StackPanel>
              <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ADAttributes}"></ComboBox>
              <DataGrid x:Name="fieldGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ADAttributes}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Entry.ADEntryName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding DataAttributes}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
             </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

In the first ComboBox everything is right!

I mean the problem is the Binding for the `DataGrid` which makes the lists invisible.

The Lists are of type `ObsevableCollection`.

What should I do?

Comment: *"I can not modify the static resources at run time"* -- there is no such thing as "a static resource". There are *resources*, and the *resources* **are not "static"**. `StaticResource` is a markup extension which *finds* a resource once, when the XAML is parsed. `DynamicResource` is a markup extension which finds a resource, but will also continue to update the target when the resource is replaced at run time.

Comment: *"the lists are unavailable in the ComboBox Tag, but they are outside the Grid available"* -- please show what you tried. I think you've got fragments of two different versions of your code here.

Comment: I think this is one way to get this working: `ItemsSource="{Binding ADAttributes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`. **Important:** Is `ADAttributes` an ObservableCollection? When you replace `ADAttributes` with a new collection, does the `ADAttributes` property raise PropertyChanged correctly?

Comment: Can you post the ViewModel please? And also the entire View?  The reason is so we can eliminate common databinding issues and understand better how it all ties together.  You've done a good job explaining it but, at least for me, I need to see the bigger picture and what's implemented already.  Also, post what worked first so we can see what you did differently.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post :) 
your suggestion didnt work unfortunately :(
@EdPlunkett

Comment: @Taher Show me what you tried. I agree with Michael: Please show enough context to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII give me just a bit and I will post it :)

Comment: I have edited the post!